# Generate blank canvas and insert images programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

this might be a long shot but here it goes anyway:
Suppose I have a couple of images inside a folder. Is there a way I can create a blank image and place them (with X and Y coordinates) into it?
Just in case I have not been clear enough, what I would like to do is:
1) Generate a blank image
2) Insert into that blank image some other images
In few words, this should create a blank canvas where I want to insert a few images (pictures, for example) later.
(BTW, this is a Windows project in C#)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the System.Drawing.Image and Graphics.DrawImage() classes in the .Net library. Between them, they should allow you to read, draw and save images.